# jQuery: Removing an "almost" empty div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following html:

```
<div id='foo'>
  <div class='prodbar'>
    <div class='title'>Group 1</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #1</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #2</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #3</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='prodbar'>
    <div class='title'>Group 2</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #5</div>
  </div>
  <div class='prodbar'>
    <div class='title'>Group 3</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #6</div>
    <div class='product'>Product #7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have code that adds the class `'selected'` to any product that is clicked.  After some products are selected, the user can click a button which removes the selected products from the screen, which is simply:

```
$(".selected").remove();
```

Now, if that empties a product group, I'd like the div surrounding the group div to be removed as well.  So in the above example, if Product #5 is selected and removed, I want the prodbar that now has nothing but a title to be removed with it.

I know I can accomplish what I want with a loop, but I was hoping for something more jQuery-elegant.  Essentially, I need to know if a div has only 1 child.  I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm not sure if this is doable directly in the selectors.  Any ideas?

Comment: Will every product have a key word in it like `Product` in your example above?

Comment: Every product will have a common class to indicate that it is a product, same with product groups.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help.  It looks like there's a pretty good consensus on how to handle this.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you looking for a clean up code then below will filter all prodbar and removes if title is the only children,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/KeRgq/16/)

```
$('button').click(function() {

    $('.selected').parent().filter(function() {
       if ($(this).children().not('.selected').length <= 1) { //remove the prodbar
          return true;
       } else { //remove selected alone
          $(this).find('.selected').remove();
          return false;
       }
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: `if(!$prodParent.children('product').length)`

Comment: @Dalen there could be `product` that doesn't have class `selected` in prodbar and in that case your condition will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(".selected").each(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings(".product:not(.selected)").length == 0) {
        $(this).parent(".prodbar").remove();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FaF5t/

Comment: I love the demo using my example.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".product.selected").remove();

$(".prodbar").each(function(){
    if($(this).children('.product').length == 0)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Also, if every product has a key word (like `Product`) you could remove the groups with out using `.each()`:

```
$(".prodbar:not(:contains(Product))").remove();
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/KeRgq/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know if a particular element has only one child, you can test for that directly:

```
if ($('#selector').children().length <= 1) {
    $('#selector').remove();
};
```

If you're not using a unique selector, be sure to use `.each` to [test each one individually](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/9jEJn/):

```
$('.selector').each(function(i,el) {
    if ($(this).children().length <= 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    };
};
```

Comment: Right, but the user could empty multiple groups at one time.  I'd like to be able to do it all at once.  If that's not possible, I will resort to a loop and a check.

Comment: @JerseyMike Please clarify your comment. What's different about your multiple groups that `$('.selector')` wouldn't search them all?

Comment: The user could remove all of the products from two groups.  Clicking the product just selects it.  When they push the button, first all of the selected products are removed.  Then I want to remove all of the "empty" product groups.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
$('.selected').remove();

$('.prodbar').each(function(){
    if ($(this).children().length <= 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/NMm8P/